# configure setuptools.setup to include another package as a subpackage

Tags: python, python-3.x

My project layout is

```
project_root_directory
├── setup.py
├── examples
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── ...
├── src
    └── mypkg/
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── subpkg1/
        │   ├── __init__.py
        │   ├── ...
        │   └── module1.py
        └── subpkg2/
            ├── __init__.py
            ├── ...
            └── module2.py
```

and I want to configure `setuptools.setup` s.t. the package `examples` is installed as a subpackage of `mypkg`.

I.e. after `pip install [-e] .` and opening an interpreter I want

```py
import mypkg
print(dir(mypkg.examples))
```

to show me the objects available in the respective package.

In `setup.py` I tried

```py
import os.path
from glob import glob

from setuptools import find_packages, setup

setup(
   name = 'mypkg',
   ...
   packages = find_packages('src') + ['mypkg.examples'],
   package_dir = {
      'mypkg': 'src/mypkg',
      'mypkg.examples': 'examples',
   },
   py_modules = [
        os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(path))[0] for path in glob("src/*.py")
    ],
   ...
)
```

(following https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/package_discovery.html)

The installation using `pip install -e .` is runs without error, but `mypkg.examples` is not available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer myself

The trick is to assemble the packages and `package_dir` map explicitly.

```py
import os.path
from glob import glob

from setuptools import find_packages, setup

src_packages = find_packages("src")
package_dir = dict(
    [(p, f'src/{p.replace(".", "/")}') for p in src_packages]
)

packages = src_packages + ['mypkg.examples']
package_dir['mypkg.examples'] = 'examples'

setup(
   name = 'mypkg',
   ...
   packages = packages,
   package_dir = package_dir,
   ...
)
```

After `pip install .`, `examples` is available via `from mypkg import examples`.